# Using bootswatch with Django Dojo

Tags: django, dojo, bootswatch

I am working on an app that uses Django + Dojo. I want the UX to have awesome fonts, bootswatch kind of themes for example https://bootswatch.com/3/cosmo/

The entire app is going to be written in python and want to understand how I can ensure I get the modern look interface rather than the arcane Microsoft UI like feel some of the older dojo widgets spit out.

Comment: BTW I know dijit has Claro Tundra Soria Nihilo themes, but still not satisfied with the looks as it shows on https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html#available-themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided not to go with Dojo which was too heavyweight to upload into AppEngine and dependencies it pulls 7K+ files.

Instead I donwloaded a bootstrap template, css, javascript etc, and blended that with a plan django and it works awesome!

I have posted a sample of how I did this if you are curious.
https://github.com/suramakr/django-playground/tree/master/locallibrary